# Jackson: Set class/object properties that are not coming from JSON when deserializing

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I've got the following POJO:

```
public class POJO {
  private final String id;
  private final String name;
  // constructor, getters omitted
}
```

And here's my JSON:

```
{
  "name":"foo"
}
```

I get the `id` value from somewhere else in my code.

I'd like to combine my external `id` value with the JSON somehow, so Jackson can build an instance of `POJO` which contains both values.

Here's some example code:

```
public void deserialize() {
  ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

  String id = "123";
  String json = "{\"name\":\"foo\"}";

  POJO pojo = om.readValue(json, POJO.class);

  System.out.println(pojo.getId());
  System.out.println(pojo.getName());
}
```

How can I tell Jackson to set the `id` value?

---

I already figured out I can use `om.readTree(json)` and then cast it to `ObjectNode` and then `put("id", id)` and then create an `om.readerFor(POJO.class)` and call `readValue(objectNode)`. But I guess that Jackson will now do its work twice.

Is there any other way to simply inject some external properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the correct solution:

### `@JacksonInject`

Example:

```
public class POJO {
  @JacksonInject("id")
  private final String id;
  private final String name;
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
public void deserialize() {
  ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

  String id = "123";
  String json = "{\"name\":\"foo\"}";

  InjectableValues values = new InjectableValues.Std().addValue("id", id);

  POJO pojo = om.reader(values).forType(POJO.class).readValue(json);

  System.out.println(pojo.getId());
  System.out.println(pojo.getName());
}
```

If there's any better / faster / easier solution, feel free to add another answer `:)`